# How to send an UDP datagram to an IGMP device?

Tags: python, c, network-programming

I have a broadband Radar that I want to turn on. To turn it on I have to send two registers like following:

```
    int reg0[3] = {0x00, 0xC1, 0x01};      
    int reg1[3] = {0x01, 0xC1, 0x01};
```

The main issue is that my Radar device is working on UDP protocol and works in IGMP (3rd layer of the ISO model). I have read a lot about UDP sending in these sites from the IBM support:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.hala001/cskudp.htm
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/setopt.htm
…and others.

I fathom it is neither obliged to create a `struct ip_mreq` nor add options with `setsockopt()` for I only want to send a datagram.

I have already tried to do this sort of things:

```
    #define IPM struct ip_mreq
    IPM mcast;
    int sock_err = bind(skemit, (SA *) &emit, lemit);
    mcast.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = MCAST_JOIN_GROUP;//multicastaddress 
    mcast.imr_interface.s_addr = add1;
    setsockopt(semit, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mcast, sizeof(IPM)); //sizeof(mcast)
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SAI struct sockaddr_in
#define SA struct sockaddr

int main(){

  SAI emit;
  uint32_t add1 = htonl(inet_addr("236.6.7.10")); //host address
  unsigned short port = htons(6680); // port

  memset(&emit, '\0', sizeof(emit));
  emit.sin_family = AF_INET;
  emit.sin_port = port;
  emit.sin_addr.s_addr = add1;
  socklen_t lemit = sizeof(SAI);

  int skemit = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (skemit == -1){ perror("creating socket"); }
  /*
  * Send a message to the multicast address specified by the
  * emit sockaddr structure.
  */

  int reg0[3] = {0x00, 0xC1, 0x01};        //turn_on
  int reg1[3] = {0x01, 0xC1, 0x01};        //turn_on


  /* Send the message in reg0 and reg1 to the server */

  if (sendto(skemit, reg0, sizeof(reg0), 0, (SA*)&emit, lemit) < 0){perror("sending datagram message reg0");}
  if (sendto(skemit, reg1, sizeof(reg1), 0, (SA*)&emit, lemit) < 0){perror("sending datagram message reg1");}
}
```

I receive this errors:

```
sending datagram message reg0: Network is unreachable
sending datagram message reg1: Network is unreachable
```

Could you help me?

Comment: The error "Network is unreachable" means that there's no route to the destination host. A router somewhere along the way simply don't know how to forward your message.

Comment: Or maybe your own host doesn't have a route to that mcast address. You are correct in that you don't  have to join the mcast group. NB it should be `emit.sin_port = htons(port);`.

Comment: Well, you have said it... IGMP is at the same level as UDP.  it is like trying to send a UDP packet to TCP.  You can do it, but with what sense?  PROTOCOLS are protocols, and you have to follow the rules to use them.

Comment: You are not sending your UDP packet to IGMP, but to UDP, destination port 6680.  To send a packet to IGMP, you need to select IGMP protocol, in the `socket(2)` call, if the kernel has support fot IGMP sockets.)  protocol 0 is the default `AF_INET` datagram protocol, which is `UDP`, not `IGMP`.  I think you have a little mesh with protocols.

Comment: Ok @LuisColorado, I think I haven't clearly exposed my issue. I know that UDP is the transport layer (4th) and IGMP is as the same level as routers. But I do not know how to send datas to any route without working on IP protocol. Both the device (radar) and my display unit (pc) work with UDP and IGMP.

Answer (score 0):

I have advanced in my issue, that is why I want to partially answer: I managed to do the connection in python. It cannot be a computer's settings' problem.

Here is the code that works:

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '236.6.7.8'
MCAST_PORT = 6678

HOST2 = '236.6.7.10'
PORT2 = 6680

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)



sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))  # use MCAST_GRP instead of '' to listen only
                         # to MCAST_GRP, not all groups on MCAST_PORT


mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

reg0=bytes([0x00, 0xC1, 0x01])               #turn_on
reg1=bytes([0x01, 0xC1, 0x01])               #turn_on


sock2.sendto(reg0, (HOST2, PORT2))
sock2.sendto(reg1, (HOST2, PORT2))
sock2.sendto(reg3, (HOST2, PORT2))
pcapfile = open('ragar.txt', 'w')
while True:
  pcapfile.write(str(sock.recv(65536)))
pcapfile.close()
print('the end')
```

The `sock2` manages to send the registers to the device whereas the `sock` receives the datas correctly.

Comment: And so, I do not succeed to translate it…